# Symfony2: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object even though there is an object?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I keep getting this error:

```
    /* ... */
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $movie = $em->getRepository('MyMyBundle:Movie')->findMovieByName('moviename'); // Repository Class
    \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($movie); // dumps the object just fine! The Repository found it
    echo $movie->getId(); // brings me the error nevertheless
```

Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in ... on line ...

I have the getId() method in my Entity. Other methods also don't work even though it ***is*** and object!

The object gets dumped like:

```
..... array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#759 (59) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string( .....
```

Any hints?

Comment: Are you using a custom entity repository? If yes, then please post the `findMovieByName` method.

Comment: Thanks gilden. Yes, it was a custom entity repository. But I found the answer (took me about an hour now). :) Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer: `echo $movie[0]->getId();` (the repository returned an array of objects). Sorry, sometimes you lose sight of the wood for the trees.

Comment: To simplify your code somewhat, you should use the Query::getSingleResult or Query::getOneOrNullResult methods on your repository. They each return a single result, throwing an exception if more than one result is available. Additionally, getSingleResult throws an exception if no result is available.